# How to calculate mean of multiple measures after removing outliers in R

Tags: r, mean, outliers

I have three independent measures of a variable, and they are subject to a lot of noise and sporadic sources of error that can be quite large. I would like to discard the value furthest away from the others, remember which one is discarded, and then calculate the mean with the remaining two. For example,

```
a   b   c
15  6   7
11  10  3
5   12  6
```

would become

```
a   b   c   ave     discard
15  6   7   6.5     15
11  10  3   10.5    3
5   12  6   5.5     12
```

Comment: If the three values are `1000`, `2000` and `3000`, which one would you discard? Perhaps you should be using the median if you want a robust measure of central tendency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
ddf
   a  b c
1 15  6 7
2 11 10 3
3  5 12 6

ddf$ave = apply(ddf[1:3], 1, function(x) {
 x = sort(x)
 ifelse(abs(x[1]-x[2]) > abs(x[2]-x[3]), mean(x[2:3]), mean(x[1:2]))
 }
 )

ddf$discard = apply(ddf[1:3], 1, function(x) {
 x = sort(x)
 ifelse(abs(x[1]-x[2]) > abs(x[2]-x[3]), x[1], x[3])
 }
 )

ddf
   a  b c  ave discard
1 15  6 7  6.5      15
2 11 10 3 10.5       3
3  5 12 6  5.5      12
```

Answer (score 0):

You question is underspecified. Say the three values are `1000`, `2000` and `3000`. Which would you discard? Should the answer be `1500` or `2500`?

If all you're looking for is a robust measure of central tendency, the median might be a good start (`?median` in R).

Comment: Great solution, thank you. Regarding underspecification, there is theoretical possibility of a tie, but unlikely in my setting as the actually numbers go out to many decimal places. I think I could build in provision for a tie based on code above